# How is "multiple file descriptors refer to the same socket" created?

Tags: file-descriptors, socket

The Linux Programming Interface says

> 56.5.5 Connection Termination: close()
>
> The usual way of terminating a stream socket connection is to call close(). If **multiple
> file descriptors refer to the same socket**, then the connection is terminated when **all
> of the descriptors** are closed.

What data structures does the kernel use for sockets? Are they similar to those for regular files:

- file descriptor table
- file description table
- vnode table?

Does "multiple file descriptors refer to the same socket" mean the same as "multiple
file descriptors refer to the same socket description"?

How is "multiple file descriptors refer to the same socket" created? Is it created by `dup()` or some socket-specific functions?

I have seen two different definitions of sockets before:

- a socket is the same as a port (TCP port, UDP port)
- a TCP socket is identified by a connection, so multiple sockets can correspond to the same TCP port. (I guess this is the definition used in Socket API)

Which definition of socket does the quote use in "multiple file descriptors refer to the same socket" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer is to remember that the file descriptor is just a reference to the actual socket and you can have multiple file descriptors referring the same socket. Reference counting is used to terminate the socket when the last reference is removed.

So, yes, you can `dup(2)` a socket file descriptor.

The longer explanation is that a file descriptor is just user space handle for a kernel inode. The kernel `struct inode` has a pointer to a kernel `struct socket` which is a higher-level, generic socket interface. That structure will have a pointer to a lower-level `struct sock` which is the actual tcp/ip socket. Remember, you can have sockets for other address families. Note, this explanation is still somewhat simplified.

To answer your last question, both definitions are correct with regards to the quote.

This blog post actually does a pretty good job of explaining part of the process of creating a socket and allocating a filedescriptor: https://ops.tips/blog/how-linux-creates-sockets/

Comment: Thanks. is it correct that a socket fd refers to an open file description, which in turn refers to an `inode` object, which in return refers to a `socket` object, which refers to a `sock` object? So is a `socket` object in the same position as a disk file?

Comment: So, the first question, basically yes. The second question, likely no; but, I don't know exactly what you're asking by, "in the same position." They have some things in common but many things that are distinctly not.